# AngularJS $http not responding

Tags: php, angularjs

Im trying to save newcontact into a table inside my database and then show the table but it does not work and I can not find out why. When I hit the save button it doesnt even put anything into the database. $http.get does not work aswell.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.controller("mainController", function($scope, $http, $location){

    $scope.newcontact = {};

    $scope.get = function(){
        $http.get("backend.php").success(function(response){
            $scope.list = response;
        });
    };

    $scope.save = function(){
        if($scope.newcontact.sauna){
            $scope.newcontact.sauna = "joo";
        }else{
            $scope.newcontact.sauna = "ei";
        }   
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'backend.php',
            data: $scope.newcontact,
            header: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
        }).success(function(response){
            $scope.list = response;
            $scope.newcontact = {};
            $location.path("/list");
        });         
    };
});
```

backend.php

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "harjoitus21");

if(file_get_contents("php://input")){

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $obj = json_decode($data);

    $nimi = strip_tags($obj->name);
    $email = strip_tags($obj->email);
    $ruoka = strip_tags($obj->ruoka);
    $sauna = strip_tags($obj->sauna);

    $conn->query("INSERT INTO ilmot (nimi, email, ruoka, sauna) VALUES ('$nimi', '$email', '$ruoka', '$sauna');");
}

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ilmot");

$resultArray = array();

if($result){
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }
}

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

form.html

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="save()">    
        <input ng-model="newcontact.name" type="text" class="form-control">

        <input ng-model="newcontact.email" type="text" class="form-control">

        <select ng-model="newcontact.ruoka" class="form-control">
            <option>Kala</option>
            <option>Liha</option>
            <option>Kasvis</option>
        </select>

        <input ng-model="newcontact.sauna" type="checkbox"> 

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have checked those queries are working and backend.php is locating in the same directory as the app.js so i quess it cant be about the url either.

Comment: You said backend.php is located in the same directory as app.js - are both in the root folder of your site or are they in a subdirectory?

Comment: they are in a subdirectory.

Comment: Won't setting `url: 'backend.php'` cause it to look in the root folder for that file? *(Note: I have no idea how routing in PHP works so my apologies if this is insignificant)*

Comment: Does not seem to help if i put root/subdirectory/backend.php or subdirectory/backend.php

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Can you see the post being attempted on the network tab?

Comment: It doesnt give any errors on the page but in network tab it says "POST http://localhost/backend.php 404 (Not Found)" and i dont understand why it does that because i put everything to www/harjoitus21/ and i changed url to '/harjoitus21/backend.php'

Comment: Okay everything is working except it does not show the "nimi" on the list im trying to repeat it at. It saying "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" but i dont see the problem.